# Is every element in $(P(X),\cap,\cup)$ a zero divisor?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $X$ be a non empty set.

Is every element in $(P(X),\cap,\cup)$ a zero divisor?

Comment: As a start, note that if $X$ has only one element the ring is a field.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A\subset X$ and consider the "multiplication" with its complement. This will always be "zero." But beware to figure out if this really means that *every* element is a zero divisor. (But maybe you just forgot to reproduce a condition in your question.)